# count equal adjacent element of array

Tags: matlab

I've a vector

```
A = [0;1;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;2;2;2;2];
```

and I want to count the number of equal adjacent values in order to have a matrix like this:

```
B=[0 1
   1 3
   0 2
   1 3
   2 4];
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short solution:

```
J=find(diff([A(1)-1; A]));
B=[A(J), diff([J; numel(A)+1])];
```